# Implementation dynamic allocation of structure in C

Tags: c, syntax

Can anyone tell me why is my code not working?
It is Compiles properly but during execution, it stops giving an error message.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct book
{
    char cName[100];
    float fPrice;
};
struct book *ptr;

void display(int j)
{
    int i=0;
    ptr = ptr - j;
    while(i<j)
    {
        printf("Book name: %s\n",ptr->cName);
        printf("Price: %f\n\n",ptr->fPrice);
        ptr++;
        i++;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("How many entries do you want to make: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    ptr = (struct book*)malloc(n*sizeof(struct book));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Name: ");
        scanf("%s",ptr->cName);
        printf("Enter price: ");
        scanf("%f",ptr->fPrice);
        ptr++;  
    }
    display(n);
    return 0;
}
```

DISCLAIMER: I am very new to C, if my coding hurts your eyes, I sincerely apologize in advance. Just looking to understand the program rather than quickly finish it.

Comment: The line `scanf("%f",ptr->fPrice);` should be `scanf("%f",&ptr->fPrice);` Function `scanf` needs the *address* of the variable. In the previous-but-one line, the array *decays* to a pointer so does not need the `&`.

Comment: Don't modify `ptr` — you need to preserve the value returned by `malloc()` so that you can release the memory later.  Use `ptr[i]` (or `ptr[i].cName`, etc) in both `main()` and `display()`.  It would be better to pass `ptr` and `n` to `display()` — avoid global variables whenever possible.  (As written, you'd need to write `free(ptr - n)` in `main()` to release the data.  That's not idiomatic C.)  Also, you could (should) be systematic; you use a `for` loop in `main()`, and there's no reason not to do the same in `display()`.

Comment: ...and although you say it compiles properly, there is a compiler warning about it.

Answer (score 3):

This here:

```
scanf("%f",ptr->fPrice);
```

Has to be this:

```
scanf("%f",&ptr->fPrice); // with a "&"
```

Because you want to pass a pointer to a `float`.

---

On another note, always listen to your compiler's warnings. They can point out code patterns that are commonly errors. For instance, your code might cause a warning among the lines of `'scanf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double'`.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation, but why is the pointer arithmetic "wrong"?  It is unusual, and idiosyncratic rather than idiomatic, but … what's actually wrong?

Comment: Correcting the `&` fixes the output. Although unconventional, the pointer usage was not faulty.

Comment: Yes, it's now working for me, too. It seems that the error is on my part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You might note that the book titles must have just a single word — typing "Treasure Island" as the title runs into problems — there are many ways to deal with that problem, but some care is required.